# Accessing different parts of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have put together a menu using a md array, but I am having problems getting the sub menu items to print out properly.

I use this to build the menus:

```
class Language {

public $langCode ;

function __construct($code)
{
    $this->langCode = $code ;
}

public function navigation()
{
    if($this->langCode == 'en')
    {
        $menu = array(
                      array('Home', ''),
                      array('Galleries', '',
                            array('Top ten hottest' => 'hottest.php'),
                            array('Top ten worst' => 'hottest.php'),
                           ),
                      array('Upload', 'upload.php'),
                      array('Login/register', ''),
                      array('Resources', '', 
                            array('News' => ''),
                            array('What\'s a mound?' => ''),
                            array('Legal' => ''),
                            array('Links' => ''),
                           ),
                      array('abc?', ''),
                     ) ;
    }
    return $menu ;
}
```

}

And I am trying to build the menu using:

```
$mainMenu = $lng->navigation() ;

echo "<ul>\n" ;
foreach($mainMenu as $set) {
    $x = 0 ;
    echo "<li><a href='".$set[1]."'>".$set[0]."</a></li>\n" ;
    if($set[2])
    {
        foreach($set[2] as $label => $item) {
            echo $item ;
        }
    }
}
```

But all I'm getting is the first item from the sub menu from the foreach loop which makes no sense to me because I can access it directly by doing $set[2][0] (before I assigned keys to the values in the arrays).

What do I need to do to get the output I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to make set[2] an array. Right now you have set[2] and set[3] and on resources you have set[4] and set[5] also:

```
$menu = array(
                  array('Home', ''),
                  array('Galleries', '', array(
                        array('Top ten hottest' => 'hottest.php'),
                        array('Top ten worst' => 'hottest.php'),
                       )),
                  array('Upload', 'upload.php'),
                  array('Login/register', ''),
                  array('Resources', '', array(
                        array('News' => ''),
                        array('What\'s a mound?' => ''),
                        array('Legal' => ''),
                        array('Links' => ''),
                       )),
                  array('abc?', ''),
                 ) ;
```